# can I draw a line with different color by matlab in kml file format

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to write line in kml file format with malab, this line is multiple color according to signal level or multiple line discontinuity? 
by using 'kmlwriteline' it possible to write a line with one color, but I need to draw thie line with different color according to signal level or between to 3 color red,green,yellow 
thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do that. First one is, you can get the function [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34006-kml-line-plot/content/kml_line.m) or `kmlwrite()`function and can use its color specification.

Second one is you can generate your one colour line and can open the kml file with Google Earth application then you can change the colour of line by right clicking on lines. The second one is manual way.

**Edit:** I see your point. You must create `geoshape` objects to perform your task briefly. ***If you want to segment the current line you must use NaN value.***

Now try to code below:

```
% % // import your excel file
lat      = xlsread('hossain1.xlsx','data','A2:A445');
lon      = xlsread('hossain1.xlsx','data','B2:B445');
Rx_Level = xlsread('hossain1.xlsx','data','C2:C445');

% Initializing some stuff
Rx    = [-60 -70 -80 -90 -100];
color = ['g', 'y', 'r', 'k']; % // I adjusted the colour wrt your uploaded pic.
width = 12 : -3 : 3;          % // In the pic, Rx levels have a different witdh lines.

% // Existing Geographic shape object
lines = geoshape();

len = length(lat);

for u = 2 : length(Rx)
    indexWrtRxLevel                      = ( Rx_Level >= Rx(u) ) & ( Rx_Level < Rx(u-1) );
    lines(u-1).Latitude                  = zeros(1, len);
    lines(u-1).Longitude                 = zeros(1, len);
    indexOfZeros                         = find(indexWrtRxLevel == 0);
    indexOfOnes                          = find(indexWrtRxLevel == 1);
    lines(u-1).Latitude( indexOfZeros )  = NaN;
    lines(u-1).Longitude( indexOfZeros ) = NaN;
    lines(u-1).Latitude( indexOfOnes )   = lat( indexOfOnes );
    lines(u-1).Longitude( indexOfOnes )  = lon( indexOfOnes );
    lines(u-1).Name                      = ['>= ', num2str(Rx(u)), ' dBm'];
    lines(u-1).Color                     = color(u-1);
    lines(u-1).Width                     = width(u-1);   
end

filename = 'Rx Levels';
kmlwrite(filename, lines, ...
    'Name', lines.Name, ...
    'Color', lines.Color, ...
    'Width', lines.Width);
```

What I got is:
[image]

I hope that would be useful.

Comment: it doesn't work, you can see this picture to understand what i need
(http://lib.convdocs.org/pars_docs/refs/130/129547/129547_html_m61e09a02.jpg)

Comment: can I draw like this with matlab, line with color acording to rxsignal level. thanks a lot

Comment: You have latitude and longitude data of those lines and rx signal levels of those, right?

Comment: Ok then there is no problem. You can import those data to MATLAB right? What do you mean exactly, when you say it didn' t work?

Comment: ok, kmlwriteline connect between the points, when I try to draw each line separately it showes as a continue line.

Comment: Error using kmlparse (line 36)
The parameter/value inputs must be pairs.
Error in kmlwrite (line 318)
[filename, S, options] =  kmlparse(mfilename, 'any', varargin{:});
Error in mehmet (line 21)
kmlwrite(filename, lines, ...

Comment: thank you mehemt, I put your cobe to m file and change the input to be form xlsread(...), but when I run there are an error in massage above. thank for you again.

Comment: Hmm. I supposed it would work. Because of not having the data I could not examine it. But I think those functions anda method are what you looked for. I hope you would figure it out. Good luck with that..

Comment: I could send to you my data if you still interesting to help me on this, my email heljamal82@gmail.com

Comment: Ok. I will contact you if it can wait for two days. My pc is not with me right now.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for you, I'll try to do something on this... thanks a lot